# JavaFX - Methods creating a new BooleanExpression cause memory leaks

Tags: memory-leaks, javafx-2, boolean-expression

I have just noticed that methods not(), and(), or() from both classes BooleanExpression and Bindings create a new BooleanExpression which probably stays in memory even if it does not have any reference.

```
myBool = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
 for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
 myBool.not();
}
```

Aforementioned code creates about 530 MB which stay in memory until the 'myBool' variable is dereferenced (and cleaned).

Is this a bug or normal behavior? If so, is there any way how to clean the memory without loosing 'myBool' variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a bug, when you are invoking [not()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/binding/BooleanExpression.html#not%28%29) you are creating a [BooleanBinding](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/binding/BooleanBinding.html). This binding is bound to the `SimpleBooleanProperty` using the listener mechanism. That means that the `SimpleBooleanProperty` keeps a **strong reference** on the binding.

The binding must be "unbound" from the property. The [dispose()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/binding/BooleanBinding.html#dispose%28%29) method does the trick;

```
BooleanBinding binding = myBool.not();
binding.dispose();
```

Note that the javadoc of this method is not very accurate.